# Como aplicar serializer a um objeto gerado pelo FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, active-model-serializers

Tenho um objeto `user` gerado pelo `FactoryGirl` como o abaixo:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name     { FFaker::NameBR.name }
    image    { FFaker::Avatar.image }
    email    { FFaker::Internet.email }
    password 'Passw0rd!'
  end
end
```

Minha serializer não trás `image`:

```
module Api::V1
  class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :name, :email
  end
end
```

Ao tentar comparar o objeto gerado pela controller e um mock do `FactoryGirl` obtenho um erro de comparação.

```
expect(json).to eq(JSON.parse(@user.to_json))
```

Minha dúvida é como aplicar serializer ao mock do `FactoryGirl`? Obrigado.

Comment: Talvez a forma que estou pensando esteja errada, talvez exista uma melhor alternativa, gostaria desse feedback. :]

Comment: Posta aqui os jsons gerados pra que possamos ver as diferenças